# How to get excel to match dates and data then return a value

Tags: excel, vba, date, match

I am not sure if the functions I am using are wrong or if excel just won't recognize the dates. I have checked the formatting already.

I have this data in columns

```
       A        B             
1 CoyVCD    12/21/2012  
2 CoyVCE    12/24/2012  
3 CoyVCI    12/24/2012  
4 CoyVCC    12/25/2012  
5 CoyVCC    12/26/2012  
6 CoyVCE    12/26/2012  
7 CoyVCD    12/27/2012  
8 CoyVCH    12/27/2012
```

and I need it in a different format with a resulting value for true/false matches.

The format I want is

```
         D           E         F          G          H          I   
    7           12/21/2012 12/22/2012 12/23/2012 12/24/2012 12/25/2012  
8  CoyVCD                               
9  CoyVCE                                       
10 CoyVCI  
11 CoyVCC                                                                                                                           
12 CoyVCH                                           
13 CoyVCA
```

The dates in my desired format are consecutive. The data in the columns above have a specific date (not consecutive) for each "Coy" data value. I want to enter a formula in each cell of my desired format that says if the "Coy" value in A matches the one in D AND the date in B matches the one in E, then 1 should be the resulting value. If not, 0 should be the value.

I have tried =`IF((COUNTIFS(A:A,A1,D:D,D8)+(B1=E7)),"1","0")`

I have also tried =`IF((COUNTIFS(A:A,A1,D:D,D8)+COUNTIFS(B:B,B1,E:E,E7))"1","0")`

But I can only get the first one to enter successfully and then it doesn't seem to recognize matching dates and returns the wrong values, or it is leaving out the second half of the formula all together.

For example, if it worked correctly, there would be a 1 in E8 and a 0 in E9.

I appreciate any help with this. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You need to understand absolute, relative and mixed references to get your formulas to work properly. Some reference need to remain fixed, such as the range for the A and B columns. This formula works for your range of sample data.

```
=SUMPRODUCT(($A$1:$A$8=$D8)*1,($B$1:$B$8=E$7)*1)
```

You can use $A:$A and $B:$B instead if you need to handle an expanding list, but it slows down the formulas a lot.

The formulas would be sped up by first selecting your source data and then inserting a table. Then creating the SUMPRODUCT formula selecting the data ranges in the table. The table and references in the SUMPRODUCT formula will expand automatically with new rows.

Answer (score 1):

You could also just insert a pivot table and count the combinations.

Again, insert a table first to automatically expand with new data. Then insert a PivotTable, setting the Coy values to Row labels, Date values to Column Labels, then drag either field to Values to count the combinations. Right click on the PivotTable and click Refresh after adding more values to the table.

[image: IMG]

Answer (score 1):

Another formula that could be used is

```
=MIN(1,COUNTIFS($A:$A,$D8,$B:$B,E$7))
```

Place that in cell E8 and copy to the range E8:I13.

Comment: This is also far more efficient when using full column references.